# WordPress multi-site, how to select other sites that are not the main one

Tags: wordpress, customization, footer, multisite

I'm working in WordPress... and I need to show different post on the footer. The thing is... I had a multi-site with two sites, so It was easy to customize as I want each footer with

```
if(is_main_site()) {

} else {

}
```

But now I have added another site, how can I select, with php one site or other?

I have checked WordPress codex, but I can only find is_main_site referring to multi-site.... does anyone has an idea about what can I use?

Thank you

Comment: it's also called network; there are 4 functions for that, including one that provides the site url: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/network_site_url

Comment: yes yes I know but I still have the same problem, I can add code for the main site or the current site, and I need to customize the 3rd site. So the main site is the portal site, and then I have two other sites "site1" and "site2". Before I added site2 it was easy, because I did it using the main_site but because now I have 2 sites, obviously if I customize them within the "else", it change both, and I need to customize each one separately!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a conditional function.

WordPress provides the [get_current_blog_id()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id) function, using this function you can create a switch statement to add your custom footer.

Also, you can check the [get_blog_details](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_blog_details)function to retrieve the current site details.

Comment: aha, I haven't that function! I'm going to give it a try, thanks!